# validate tricky fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

in my form fields i've got watermark text that disappears when the user is typing something in them.

but then, i cannot use jquery validation plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example for checking that the user has typed something in the fields cause in either way, they will contain text.

so how can i validate that the user type something when they already contain watermark text and the plugin will assume they are filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use addmethod:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("watermarkmethod", function(value, element) { 
  return this.optional(element) || value != 'your watermark text'; 
}, "Please do not leave empty");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the watermark text for each field somewhere (For example the `rel` attribute of the element, or in the `title` if the watermark text is somthing like "enter your name here", or in a custom JS array for 100% clean and valid HTML) and write your own validation method that checks whether the field's content is equal to the default value.

See [**Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) on how to implement your own validation methods.